# CSS overriding CSS and jQuery UI

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

So I have a regular CSS/HTML website for my upcoming book.  It has a section called Bonus Features for extra articles that I’ve written.  They pop up using jQuery UI that reads from external HTML pages.

Because I want the titles and dates… i.e.

Hello World

May 6, 2011

…to be very close together, instead of your usual gap, I’ve created a separate CSS stylesheet (dialog.css).

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 + p {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 + p {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Unfortunately, dialog.css seems to be overriding default.css (for the website) because whenever I open then close the pop-up, the text on the Bonus Features page clutters together, reading from dialog.css, until a browser refresh.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, like a special HTML or CSS code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `dialog.css` is being loaded in the main page's scope.

if your dialog is built like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

then you can make your css like this:

```
#dialog h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and those properties will only apply to elements within an element of id `#dialog`

Comment: Thanks.  Where do I put the div id thingy though?  The template?  If so, where?  Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Ricky: That depends on how the popup is created. I'm not familiar with jQuery UI, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you for all your help! (:

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it can be as simple as minding the order that the css loads.  The last one in order defined will generally take precedence.  Yes, there are exceptions, but as a rule of thumb, put your most customized CSS file at the end of a series of CSS declarations, while loading things like jQuery UI's css first.

Comment: It's okay.  I figured it out.  Thanks so much for your suggestion. (:

Answer (score 0):

use firebug (or something similar) to find out how this property is set. to override this rule you need to use the same exact selectors or *more powerful*. thats the way CSS works and thats where the name came from.

also you may try adding `!important` after each rule.

Comment: It's okay.  I figured it out.  Thanks so much for your suggestion. (: